# Why does my GraphQL query to return one record fail, but my query to find all records works fine?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql

I have a Mongo database with a collection called 'words' which contains documents like this:

```
{
  _id: "xxxx",
  word: "AA",
  definition: "Cindery lava"
}
```

I have a node app that I am using to query and display information from the words collection, with GraphQL. I have created a GraphQL schema and Mongoose model, as shown below.

```
// Schema
const WordType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Word',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        word: { type: GraphQLString },
        definition: { type: GraphQLString },
    })
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        detailsForWord: {
            type: WordType,
            args: {word: {type: GraphQLString}},
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Word.find({word: args.word});
            }
        },
        allWords: {
            type: new GraphQLList(WordType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Word.find({}).limit(100);
            }
        }
    }
});


// model 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const wordSchema = new Schema({
    word: String,
    definition: String,
});
```

My problem is that the "allWords" query works perfectly but the "detailsForWord" does not work at all, and I have no idea why.

In GraphiQL I am using these queries:

```
{
  allWords {
    word
    definition
  }
}
```

... and

```
{
  detailsForWord(word: "AA") {
    word
    definition
  }
}
```

The former returns records, but the latter always returns the following in GraphiQL:

```
{
  "data": {
    "detailsForWord": {
      "id": null,
      "word": null,
      "definition": null
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas why the "detailsForWord" query is failing?

Comment: Update: So it turns out that Word.findOne(word: "AA") works! I still don't know why Word.find({word: "AA") doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously find returns an array of documents while findOne returns a single document. Therefore the query might be successful you are getting an array no matter what with find. findOne returns the document you are looking for. Your query didn't fail, it returned a promise with an array.

if you do

```
resolve(parent, args) {
            return Word.find({word: args.word}).then(c=>{console.log(c);return c})
}
```

You'll see an array containing the document in the console.