# How can I get user by userName in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have this RootQuery:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, {id}) {
                return User.findById(id)
            }
        },
```

and then Ill use this query to get the user:

```
{
  user(id:"5bd78614e71a37341cd2b647"){
    id
    userName
    password
    isAdmin
  }
}
```

it works just fine' now i dont want to get the user by his ID, 
I want to get him by his userName insted so I used this

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { userName: { type: GraphQLString } },
            resolve(parent, {userName}) {
                console.log('userName',userName)
                return User.find({ userName })
            }
        },
```

this will bring back the user with all properties be null
please help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my GraphQL query to return one record fail, but my query to find all records works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108686/why-does-my-graphql-query-to-return-one-record-fail-but-my-query-to-find-all-re)

Comment: `find` returns an array of users, while you're field is expecting a single user object. You need to use `findOne` or return the first element in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `findOne` to get only one user, `find` will bring you all users with that name. If you want that, maybe your return should be `type: GraphQLList(UserType)`.
If it's bringing all properties it is probably because you are asking for them on the query.
Also, you might be missing an `await User.find({ userName })`, and an `async` on your function:

```
   const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'RootQueryType',
        fields: {
            user: {
                type: UserType,
                args: { userName: { type: GraphQLString } },
                resolve: async (parent, {userName}) => {
                    console.log('userName',userName)
                    const user = await User.findOne({ userName })
                    console.log('user',user);
                    return user;
                }
            },
```

Check if this helps you :)

Comment: No i want to get one user data by the userName and password

Comment: Using findOne did fix the similar issue on my end.